# What will cause an 404 error to be consumed?

Tags: java, weblogic, http-status-code-404

We have an application running on weblogic.

For some reason after "hooking" on a monitoring tool

the web application stop responding with a 404 when an url is invalid.

Is not a big problem but we would like to understand what could cause the issue in terms of settings?

What should we look out for.

```
404 Not Found
The requested resource could not be found but may be available again in the future.[2] Subsequent requests by the client are permissible.
```

weblogic log

```
####<Jan 30, 2014 12:13:24 PM CST> <Debug> <Http> <xxxx.xxx.xxx> <advisors-ext-1> <ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1391105604570> <BEA-000000> <[HTTP:101147]HttpServer (defaultWebserver) name: advisors-ext-1 Found no context for "/". This request does not match the context path for any installed Web applications, and there is no default Web application configured.> 
####<Jan 30, 2014 12:13:24 PM CST> <Debug> <Http> <xxxx.xxx.xxx> <advisors-ext-1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1391105604571> <BEA-000000> <HttpRequest@590351528 - /: Writing headers for HttpRequest@590351528 - /> 
####<Jan 30, 2014 12:13:24 PM CST> <Debug> <Http> <xxxx.xxx.xxx> <advisors-ext-1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1391105604571> <BEA-000000> <HttpRequest@590351528 - /: Writing headers for HttpRequest@590351528 - />
```

Answer (score 0):

A 404 error is an HTTP status code that means that the page you were trying to reach on a website couldn't be found on their server.

Technically, an Error 404 is a client-side error either because you typed the URL in wrong or the page has been moved or removed from the website and you should have known.

Another possibility is if a website has moved a page or resource but did so without redirecting the old URL to the new one. When that happens, you'll receive a 404 error instead of being automatically routed to the new page.

Comment: yup i understand that, I am trying to find the technical reason for why the 404 got consumed by weblogic.

Comment: @user4127 My fault, question wasn't perfectly clear. I've never used weblogic. You'll want someone more experienced. Sorry about that